# insert line in HTML code job using shell

Tags: shell

Hi I have following sample HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
       <HEAD>
         <script src="../2.js"></script>
       </HEAD>
      <body>
        hello all!
      </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to insert a `<script>` line in `<HEAD>` section.

I tried following command:

```
sed  '/\<HEAD\>/a \<script src="../blabla.js"\>\</script\>' input.html > temp.html && mv temp.html input.html
```

But this command is inserting the line twice, one is after `<HEAD>` and another after `</HEAD>`

I want to insert only once. How I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `\<HEAD\>` with `<HEAD>`.  In other words, use:

```
sed  '/<HEAD>/a <script src="../blabla.js"></script>' input.html
```

Under GNU sed, the basic regex `\<HEAD\>` matches the word HEAD because `\<` matches the start of a word and `\>` matches the end of a word. This is in contrast to `<HEAD>` which matches what you want: `<HEAD>`.

`\<HEAD\>` matches both occurrences of the string `HEAD` in your HTML code.  The surrounding angle brackets or slashes are not matched.

In the replacement part of the substitution command, GNU interprets the escaped angle brackets to mean the same thing as just plain angle brackets.  Thus, the escapes are superfluous and are best removed.